# What is this plant resembling cannabis that is growing on my garden?

Tags: identification, planting

So I have got these seeds from neighbour and they were supposed to be tomatoes, but... as they are growing, it seems to be something else.

[image]

What is it? Could it be weed by any chance? :)

Edit: Asked a neighbour and she is having the same plant (surprised as well), but the seeds should have been something from Japan or around...

Comment: Looks vaguely like a marijuana seedling, but it should develop palmate leaves if it is. Better ask your neighbour if he's made a mistake... whatever it is, its definitely not tomato!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is definitely *Cannabis*. I think your neighbor is joking around. You can keep it even if you don't like to smoke it, it will be a wonderful plant.

Comment: Or grow it on and when it buds, make medicinal oil from it...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have asked the neighbour and updated the question accordingly. The seeds should be from Japan, so...

Comment: Yeah they should be from Japan, just like they should be tomatoes, right? That's also what my neighbor always says about his plants...

Answer (score 0):

A Japanese Maple leaf looks a lot like cannabis, but those are not 3 leafed

While weed normally has 5-7 leaves, according to a forum I just saw 3 leaves are a common mutation that growers see. Although I believe most of those growers use clones not seeds.

I tried image searching, but everything look looked just like your plant, was from a cannabis plant.

If you are in a state where growing cannabis is legal, or dont care, let it grow and see if it changes.